# How to find memory used by a function in java

Tags: java

I am calling a function from my code (written in java) and I want to know how much memory that function is using, and do keep in mind that I cannot add any code to the function(which I am calling).

for eg-

```
 //my code starts
   .
   .
   .
   .
   myfunc();
 //print memory used by myfunc() here
  .
  .
 // my code ends
```

How to do this?

Comment: @vikiii- I did try to use this-                                    "Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();". I put it before and after the call to myfunc(). and then subracted one from another to get total memory used. But its wrong, because ideally it should always be zero after subraction.

Comment: *Why* should it be zero? What if the function allocates memory on the heap that remains referenced after the function exits.

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying to do is basically pointless. There is no such thing as *memory used by a function*. Your idea of comparing the total memory usage "before" and "after" function call does not have any sense: the function may change global state (which may decrease or increase total memory usage, and in some cases (e.g. cache filling) you probably won't want to consider the increase to count as "memory used by a function), or the garbage collector may run while you're inside of `myfunc` and decrease the total used memory.

The good question often contains the large part of an answer. What you should do is to correctly ask the question.

Comment: @penartur- I am calling a remote api, and i need to test its performance, so i need to get its memory usage. So is that not possible ???

Comment: +1 The good question often contains the large part of an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *performance*? And, by the way, what do you mean by *remote API* (usually it means some SOAP- or something-based **remote** API, which runs on a **remote** server, and thus checking its memory requirements makes even less sense, as the memory is consumed on some **remote** server, not on your PC).

Comment: @penartur-  Ya , its a remote api, so that means i cannot find its memory usage. ok, ya you are right i guess. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful with this code (it's not guaranteed to work, but try it and there's a good chance it'll give you what you need):

```
final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) rt.gc();
final long startSize = rt.totalMemory()-rt.freeMemory();
myFunc();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) rt.gc();
System.out.println("Used memory increased by " +
   rt.totalMemory()-rt.freeMemory()-startSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But its wrong, because ideally it should always be zero after subraction.

Actually its right because normally each thread has a TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffer) which means it allocates in blocks (so each thread can allocate concurrently)

Turn this off with `-XX:-UseTLAB` and you will see ever byte allocated.

You should run this multiple times because other things could be running when you use this function.